# Subtracting quantity from MySQL database without getting to negative

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a C# app that reduces the quantity of a particular book in the database by 1 each time the book is issued out. The quantity keeps subtracting until it ends up with a negative value as the book quantity.

I want to know how to subtract the book quantity without reaching a negative value.

Here is the code:

```
connect = new SqlConnection(conStr.connectString);
connect.Open();
string updateString = "update tblbooks set quantity=quantity - 1 where book_id=@book_id";
cmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use  a `case` or `greatest()`:

```
update tblbooks
    set quantity = greatest(quantity - 1, 0)
    where book_id = @book_id;
```

Or, better yet, use a condition in the `where`:

```
update tblbooks
    set quantity = quantity - 1
    where book_id = @book_id and quantity >= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use where class to make sure you update only those records which have `quantity > 0`

```
update tblbooks 
set quantity=quantity - 1 
where quantity>0 and book_id=@book_id
```